# how to set css to a specific attribute of an input tag

Tags: html, css

I have the following code:

**HTML**

```
<div id=addQuesion">
  <li>
    <label>Text</label>
    <input type="text"/>
  </li>
  <li>
    <label>Try</label>
    <input type="button"/>
  </li>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#addQuesion li label {
  position: relative;
  top: 10px;
  left: 10px;
  font-size: 25px;
  border: 1px black solid;
  padding-right: 50px;
}

#addQuesion li input {
  position: relative;
  top: 10px;
  left: 10px;
  width: 400px;
  font-size: 25px;
}
```

For sure the two inputs will take the width 400px, but I am asking how to make each input (text, button) have a different width.

I know I can use style like this `<input style="..." />` but I need to use CSS. I also know that I can use different `<div>` for each input but I want to put them in the same div.

Comment: **Style note:** you shouldn't put `<li></li>` tags inside a div. They should always be inside list (`<ul></ul>` or `<ol></ol>`) tags. You may end up with strange bugs in your layout if you do it the way you've shown.

Comment: ok thank you , but is it good to use <ul> inside a div ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can target inputs by their type thus applying different styles to them:

**CSS**

```
/* Text Field */
#addQuesion input[type="text"] {
  width: 200px;
}

/* Button */
#addQuesion input[type="button"] {
  width: 20px;
}
```

You can read more about this here: [W3C Attribute Selector](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_attribute_selectors.asp)

Answer (score 4):

Use an attribute selector:

```
#addQuestion li input[type="text"]
{
   /* ... */
}
```

Or

```
#addQuestion li input[type="button"]
{
   /* ... */
}
```

This a common question.

Answer (score 2):

You can add a class to each input and define different styles for each class.

HTML:

```html
<div id=addQuesion">
    <li>
        <label>Text</label>
        <input class="input1" type="text"/>
    </li>
    <li>
        <label>Try</label>
        <input class="input2" type="button"/>
    </li>
</div>
```

CSS:

```css
#addQuesion li input.input1{
    width: 400px;
}
#addQuesion li input.input2{
    width: 600px;
}
```

Comment: is this better than
#addQuesion input[type="text"] ?

Comment: Both do the same. This class procedure can be used when you need in multiple places of the same width. The former one can be used too. When there are many li elements, typing out each text makes it messy.

Comment: Class selectors are better in the sense that they are universally supported in CSS enabled browsers. Attribute selectors are not supported by some old browsers. Though those browsers are getting rare, I would still use a class selector when dealing with just two `input` elements. (Actually, only one of them would need a `class` attribute then.)

Answer (score 1):

You can use something like this:

```
[title]
{
color:blue;
}
```

[Reference](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_attribute_selectors.asp)